# Touchpad malfunction in Lubuntu 18.10

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad, asus, 18.10, tap-to-click

I recently installed Lubuntu on an Asus Notebook. Neither touchpad tap nor touchpad scrolling worked at the start. I was able to correct the tap problem by editing the 00-keyboard.conf file in /etc/X11.However, the touchpad still does not allow vertical scrolling. I believe others have encountered this issue on previous versions of Lubuntu, but I have not been able to locate a reliable solution. Can anyone offer guidance on this problem. Thank you.

Comment: I'm also running Lubuntu on an Asus Notebook. Have you tried checking "Application Menu > Keyboard and Mouse > Mouse and Touchpad" settings? I had the same problem, just checked the box that said "Single click to activate items" and voila! Not to mention I tried installing and uninstalling various packages before that (as mentioned here: [https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2360360](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2360360)), none worked. Sometimes GUI makes it much easier.

Comment: Hi Pedram, unfortunately this method had no effect for me. The system has also since been updated, but without any change. Thanks.